# Canot assign value of type 'UIView' to type --class conforming to UIView--

Tags: ios, swift, class, uiview, casting

I have the following class conforming to UIView:

```
import UIKit

class LocationInformationCalloutView: UIView {
      :
      :
```

Then I have a second class that looks like this:

```
class LocationInformationAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
    weak var customCalloutView : LocationInformationCalloutView?
        }
    }
        :
        :
```

So you can see I have a variable called `customAnnotationView` that is of type `LocationInformationCalloutView` which is of type `UIView`

The `loadLocationInformationCalloutView()` function looks like this (just a function that returns an UIView):

```
func loadLocationInformationCalloutView() -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 240, height: 280))
    return view
}
```

However upon invoking this line of code:

```
self.customCalloutView = newCustomCalloutView
```

within this block of code:

```
 override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    if selected {
        self.customCalloutView?.removeFromSuperview()
        if let newCustomCalloutView = loadLocationInformationCalloutView() {
            newCustomCalloutView.frame.origin.x -= newCustomCalloutView.frame.width / 2.0 - (self.frame.width / 2.0)
            newCustomCalloutView.frame.origin.y -= newCustomCalloutView.frame.height
            self.addSubview(newCustomCalloutView)
            self.customCalloutView = newCustomCalloutView
            if animated {
                self.customCalloutView!.alpha = 0.0
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.8, animations: {
                    self.customCalloutView!.alpha = 1.0
                })
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'UIView' to type 'LocationInformationnCalloutView?'

Can someone shed some light on this and help me through this problem? Any help si greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocationInformationCalloutView` inherits from `UIView`, which means that you can assign an instance of `LocationInformationCalloutView` to a property whose type is `UIView`, but you cannot do so the other way around.

At the line `self.customCalloutView = newCustomCalloutView` you are trying to assign a `UIView` instance to a property of type `LocationInformationCalloutView`, which cannot work, since a parent class cannot be used in place of a child instance.

You need to change the return type of `loadLocationInformationCalloutView()` to be `LocationInformationCalloutView` instead of `UIView`.

```
func loadLocationInformationCalloutView() -> LocationInformationCalloutView {
    return LocationInformationCalloutView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 240, height: 280))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You got it the other way around. You can assign a variable of a subclass to a variable of a superclass, but you can't do the opposite for obvious reasons.

First thing, you method should be **return**ing a valid `LocationInformationCalloutView` if it is supposed to that. If you have to, for some reason return it as a `UIView`. Then you have to cast it to `LocationInformationCalloutView` before saving it in `customCalloutView`.

```
if let validCustomCalloutView = newCustomCalloutView as? LocationInformationCalloutView {
    self.customCalloutView = validCustomCalloutView
}
```

Note: The casting will fail if the `UIView` being passed is not actually an instance of `LocationInformationCalloutView`. The method should preferably look like how [@DávidPásztor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52423552/7734643) answer shows.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to instantiate the CalloutView with its own classtype like this:

```
func loadLocationInformationCalloutView() -> LocationInformationCalloutView? {
let view = LocationInformationCalloutView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 240, height: 280))
return view
```

}